# reloda data from another view, when model get and decode json

Tags: json, swift, uicollectionview, reloaddata, decodable

I have two controllers A and B

In controller A, at the click of a button, I make a request with JSON and get the data into the model, which is also its Decode

after that there is a loader and redirection to the controller B
All label and image must pick up data from the Model and update the view.

If I update the view in controller B in the viewdidload method the data is not updated. I can't understand why, I think I need to call an update from Controller A, but I'm not sure that's true.

please help with the implementation
All methods that I find hopelessly outdated

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ button: TransitionButton) {
    button.startAnimation() // 2: Then start the animation when the 
user tap the button
    let qualityOfServiceClass = DispatchQoS.QoSClass.background
    let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: 
qualityOfServiceClass)
    backgroundQueue.async(execute: { 

...request.....

button.stopAnimation(animationStyle: .expand, completion: {
let secondVC  = 
self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
    "CarInfoID") as! CarInfo

self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "navSegue", 
    sender: self)}
```

Update

or alternatively is it possible to make the controller Battery
before it was actually loaded, a query occurred.

Then the collectionView to update easier

Comment: You are giving us very little to help you with. Where is the code that stores the model? And how does View Controller B load it?

Comment: the model is in a separate  `class struct gov: Codable { controller`  A enters data into this database, which I then connect to B `var model: UaSummaryResponse!`

am I doing something wrong?